# Decrease used horizontal space of TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

How do I control the horizontal space being used by the expanded TreeViewItems so a treeview can take less space? Can it be done by styling alone or do it have to be a fully remade treeview to control these kind of styling properties?

[image: Vertical alignment]

Comment: Override the default template of the TreeViewItem and change the margin of the ItemsPresenter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items you see are layout by the `ItemsPresenter` of the parent `TreeViewItem`. This means to change the indentation of the child items you must change the position of the `ItemsPresenter` in the layout.

To do so you must override the default `ControlTemplate` of the `TreeViewItem`. Find the `ItemsPresenter` and give it a negative left `Margin` to decrease the indentation or a positive left marging to increase the indentation of the child items.

The following `Style` is taken from [Microsoft Docs: TreeView ControlTemplate Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/treeview-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#treeview-controltemplate-example). There you find all the resources that the following `Style` depends on.

The key is to set a negative left `Margin` on the `ItemsPresenter` which is named "ItemsHost":

```
<ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
                ...
                Margin="-12,0,0,0" />
```

The full TreeViewItemStyle (without resources):

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"
       TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
          Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
          Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
  <Setter Property="Padding"
          Value="1,0,0,0" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
          Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19"
                              Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                >
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
              <VisualState x:Name="SelectedInactive">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsHost">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
                        Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"
                        ClickMode="Press"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
          <Border x:Name="Bd"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                              ContentSource="Header"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
          </Border>


          <!-- Host of the child items -->
          <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
                          Grid.Row="1"
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                          Visibility="Collapsed"
                          Margin="-12,0,0,0" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                   Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="Expander"
                    Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Hidden" />
          </Trigger>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="HasHeader"
                         Value="false" />
              <Condition Property="Width"
                         Value="Auto" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Header"
                    Property="MinWidth"
                    Value="75" />
          </MultiTrigger>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="HasHeader"
                         Value="false" />
              <Condition Property="Height"
                         Value="Auto" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Header"
                    Property="MinHeight"
                    Value="19" />
          </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```